# samsung galaxy tab 2 7.0 API level/SDK Version

Tags: android, api, sdk, android-emulator, tablet

I just wanted to know what the API level or the SDK Version of the samsung galaxy tab 2 7.0 is ?
Hope you can help me :)

Comment: LMGTFY: https://www.google.com/search?q=galaxy+tab+2+wiki&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Comment: If you got the device (you did not say, that you have not got it :), you can use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` environment variable to get api level. But of course it depends on firmware updates, which user had install on device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is still on Jellybean 4.1 then it is currently sitting at API Level 16.  But as I don't know whether it has been upgraded currently that is the conclusion that we can come to from specs online if that is your question.

[Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 Update](http://support.verizonwireless.com/pdf/system_update/galaxy-tab-2.pdf)

Comment: Yeah but I thought that the Ice Cream Sandwich is still on it ?

Comment: It is possible that if the user who owns it did not get or do a firmware update that it could be on a different version than the latest available.  So, it would depend.  The build number can be obtained from the settings menu 'About Tablet' for specifics.